# OSError: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: cuda, pytorch, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia, nvidia-jetson

I am working on Nvidia Jetson Tx2 (with JETPACK 4.2) and installed the pytorch following [this link](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-6-0-now-available/72048).
When I am importing torch in python its giving me an error `OSError: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` I have tried all the options but nothing worked.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64
```

Any guidance to debug the issue is requested. Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that the library actually exists, and where it is located?

Answer (score 2):

emm
I found this answer as followed...

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/mounting-cuda-onto-l4t-docker-image-issues-libcurand-so-10-cannot-open-no-such-file-or-directory/121545

The key is : "You can use JetPack4.4 for CUDA 10.2 and JetPack4.3 for CUDA 10.0."

Maybe downloading Pytorch v1.4.0 and Jetpack 4.2/4.3 would solve this question...

Anyway, it is helped for me... good luck

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading torch from 2.0.1 to 1.4.0 worked in my case:

Pip

```
pip install pytorch==1.4.0
```

Or with poetry:

```
poetry add pytorch==1.4.0
```

Or with conda:

```
conda install pytorch==1.4.0
```